# Refresh-Problem TextFormFields not displaying a changed value

Tags: android, flutter

I'm stuck on a UI refresh problem in flutter and can't get any further. It's about geo-coordinates (variable: locInMemory), which is displayed in TextFormFields and can be updated at the push of a button. When new coordinates are determined, the variable is updated with the new coordinates and then setState() is called, i.e. UI is refreshed.

After the refresh, however, the TextFormFields still receive the old coordinates.
I have therefore inserted log outputs and Text() elements in the Ui for debugging. The updated coordinates are displayed / written to the log.

[image: Before getting new coordinates]
[image: After getting new coordinates]

Below is the programme code that builds the UI.
Many thanks for your help.

```
 print('building ui with location @ ${locInMemory.val} Lat: ${locInMemory.getLatitude()} / Lon: ${locInMemory.getLongitude()}');
    fields.add(Text(locInMemory.val));
    fields.add(Text('${locInMemory.getLatitude()} / ${locInMemory.getLongitude()} '));
    fields.add(TextFormField(
      initialValue: '${locInMemory.getLatitude()}',
      decoration: ui.asDecoration(ui.loc.attr_geo_Latitude),
      keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
    ));
    fields.add(TextFormField(
      initialValue: '${locInMemory.getLongitude()}',
      decoration: ui.asDecoration(ui.loc.attr_geo_Longitude),
      keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
    ));
```

Comment: where is controller of text form fields?

Comment: @MohammadBilalAkbar You are right! The source code is still under development - so I thought that just a new TextFormField without controller can be created, which then also displays the current value as initialValue. With controller(s) in the state, the changed value will be displayed as expected. Thanks a lot.